# Set a nested object property from a dot notation string in python

Tags: python, for-loop, split, nested

I’m writing a function that takes in a parent object `data` and a string `inputString` that may or may not include dot notation to represent nested objects (i.e. ‘nestedObject.itemA). The function should set the `inputString` attribute of `data` to a random string. If the string `inputString` is a nested object, the function should set the nested object’s value to be a random string. I can’t figure out how to handle this all in a for-loop. I want to do something like this:

```
split_objects = value.split(“.”)
for item in split_objects:
    data.__setattr__(item, get_random_string())
```

However, in the case of nested objects, the above would set the nested object to be a random string, instead of the field inside. Would someone be able to help me with the syntax to handle both cases? Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 5):

You need to get a reference to `data.nestedObject` before you can use `setattr` to change `data.nestedObject.itemA`.

```
prefix, suffix = value.rsplit(".",1)
# now prefix is nestedOjbect and suffix is itemA
ref = getattr(data,prefix)
setattr(ref,suffix,get_random_string())
```

You need to get the reference as many times as there are dots in `inputString`. So, if you have an arbitrarily deeply nested structure in `data`

```
value = "nestedObject.nestedObject2.nestedObject3.itemA"
path, attribute = value.rsplit(".",1)
path = path.split(".")
ref = data
while path:
    element, path = path[0], path[1:]
    ref = getattr(ref, element)
setattr(ref, attribute, get_random_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code I to demo a "setField" function I wrote that similar to what you are looking for:

```py
def setField(obj, fieldPath, value):
    fields = fieldPath.split(".")
    cur = obj
    # use all but the last field to traverse the objects
    for field in fields[:-1]:
        cur = getattr(cur, field)
    # use the last field as the property within the object to be overwritten (not traversed)
    setattr(cur, fields[-1], value)

# USE CASE EXAMPLE:

class PrintBase:
    def dump(self, level=0):
        for key, value in vars(self).iteritems():
            print " "*(level*4) + key + ":", value
            if isinstance(value, PrintBase):
                value.dump(level+1)

class BottomObject(PrintBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fieldZ = 'bottomX'

class MiddleObject(PrintBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fieldX = 'middleQ'
        self.fieldY = BottomObject()

class TopObject(PrintBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fieldA = 'topA'
        self.fieldB = MiddleObject()

top_obj = TopObject()
print "=== BEFORE ==="
top_obj.dump()
print "=== AFTER ==="
setField(top_obj, 'fieldB.fieldY.fieldZ', '!!!! test value !!!!')
top_obj.dump()
```

And here is the example output:

```
=== BEFORE ===
fieldB: <__main__.MiddleObject instance at 0x7f5eb1cc6b48>
    fieldX: middleQ
    fieldY: <__main__.BottomObject instance at 0x7f5eb1cc6b90>
        fieldZ: bottomX
fieldA: topA
=== AFTER ===
fieldB: <__main__.MiddleObject instance at 0x7f5eb1cc6b48>
    fieldX: middleQ
    fieldY: <__main__.BottomObject instance at 0x7f5eb1cc6b90>
        fieldZ: !!!! test value !!!!
fieldA: topA
```